# Circular SeekBar with discrete values

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am trying to create a circular seekbar with discrete non-linear values. 
I also want these values to appear outside the circle:

[image]

I looked at a number of versions from GitHub with the most promising being the one by [JesusM](https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar) 
However, I can't think of an easy way to put the values on the outside of the circle.
Can anyone think of an easy way to put the "marks" outside the circle.

The one example I did find is the time-selector for the alarm in Marshmallow. Where can I find the source for that?

Comment: have a look at https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/393

Comment: I saw that one but can't find any way to put indicator marks/values.
Otherwise, it just supplies the same functionality as the link I gave.

Comment: why dont you use background image if possible that way ?/

Comment: That's the only way I can think of at present but it is kind of "dirty". Besides, making a background with that sort of format is not going to be simple.

Comment: its dirty but now may be first option to achieve this