# Customizing Circular seek bar for discrete values

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to make a circular seek bar with discrete values.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq11C.png)

I have already seen this question [previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573841/circular-seekbar-with-discrete-values) but didn't get any insight.I also have tried a number of circular seekbar examples from GitHub but most of them are with continuous values. can anyone help to build one from scratch or to make the available ones working for discrete values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it with using paint : See my below attached code for the same.

```
public class ProgressCircle extends View {

private final RectF mOval = new RectF();
private float mSweepAngle = 0;
private int startAngle = 90;
private int angleGap = 4;
private Bitmap icon;


float mEndAngle = 1.0f;

Paint progressPaint = new Paint();
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
Paint incompletePaint = new Paint();
Paint percentagePaint = new Paint();

private float strokeWidth = 30.0f;

public ProgressCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ProgressCircle,
            0, 0);

    int textColor;
    float textSize;

    int progressColor;
    int incompleteColor;

    try {
        textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressCircle_android_textColor, Color.BLUE);
        textSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.ProgressCircle_android_textSize, 100);

        strokeWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.ProgressCircle_strokeWidth, 30.0f);

        progressColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressCircle_progressColor, Color.RED);
        incompleteColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ProgressCircle_incompleteProgressColor, Color.GRAY);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    progressPaint.setColor(progressColor);
    progressPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    progressPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    progressPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    textPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(textColor);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Roboto Condensed Light", Typeface.BOLD);
    textPaint.setTypeface(tf);

    percentagePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    percentagePaint.setColor(textColor);
    percentagePaint.setTextSize(textSize / 3);

    incompletePaint.setColor(incompleteColor);
    incompletePaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    incompletePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    incompletePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);



}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float currentAngleGap = mSweepAngle == 1.0f || mSweepAngle == 0 ? 0 : angleGap;
    mOval.set(strokeWidth / 2, strokeWidth / 2, getWidth() - (strokeWidth / 2), getWidth() - (strokeWidth / 2));
    canvas.drawArc(mOval, -startAngle + currentAngleGap, (mSweepAngle * 360) - currentAngleGap, false,
            progressPaint);

    mOval.set(strokeWidth / 2, strokeWidth / 2, getWidth() - (strokeWidth / 2), getWidth() - (strokeWidth / 2));
    canvas.drawArc(mOval, mSweepAngle * 360- startAngle + currentAngleGap, 360 - (mSweepAngle * 360) - currentAngleGap, false,
            incompletePaint);

    drawText(canvas, textPaint, String.valueOf((int) (mSweepAngle * 100)), percentagePaint);

    if(icon != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, canvas.getWidth() / 2 - icon.getWidth() / 2, strokeWidth + (canvas.getHeight() / 15), null);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}

private void drawText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, String text, Paint percentagePaint) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    Rect percentageBounds = new Rect();
    percentagePaint.getTextBounds("%", 0, 1, percentageBounds);
    int x = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (bounds.width() / 2) - (percentageBounds.width() / 2);
    int y = (canvas.getHeight() / 2) + (bounds.height() / 2);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);

    canvas.drawText("%", x + bounds.width() + percentageBounds.width() / 2, y - bounds.height() + percentageBounds.height(), percentagePaint);
}

public void setTextColor(int color) {
    textPaint.setColor(color);
}

public void setProgressColor(int color) {
    progressPaint.setColor(color);
}

public void setIncompleteColor(int color) {
    incompletePaint.setColor(color);
}

public void setProgress(float progress) {
    if (progress > 1.0f || progress < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Value must be between 0 and 1: " + progress);
    }

    mEndAngle = progress;

    this.invalidate();
}

public void startAnimation() {
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mSweepAngle, mEndAngle);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            ProgressCircle.this.mSweepAngle = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ProgressCircle.this.invalidate();
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(10000);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    anim.start();

}
```

Output Screen :          [image]

See the Complete working example [here](https://androidtutorialsrkt.blogspot.in/2017/05/circular-seekbar-in-android.html)